# AngularJS: initialize ZURB Foundation JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am using both AngularJS and Foundation.

To initialize Foundation JS, you have to make the following call:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

What would be the best way to make this call in an AngularJS application? Code examples would be appreciated.

Also, if I were to write a directive around a Foundation JS component, how could I ensure that Foundation is initialized?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is of any use to you, but there's an AngularJS port of a bunch of Foundation's javascript parts now: pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could `$apply` the code in order to bring it into the Angular framework. Here is an example using `$rootScope` with `run` and this could also be done inside a controller/directive with any `$scope`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$apply($(document).foundation());
});
```

Another option::

```
$compile($(document).foundation())($scope);
```

Be sure to include the `$compile` service in your controller/directive to use it this way.  E.g.:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $compile($(document).foundation())(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using the code example above with run doesn't seem to work. I confirmed using $compile in a controller will initialize Foundation as will simply calling '$(document).foundation();'.

Comment: Cool, that's what i was looking for, using foundation-6

Answer (score 38):

Here is my take, in `app.js`:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
});
```

which will re-initialize Foundation when a new view is loaded (so that the components contained in the new view are also initialized). This way, your controllers do not need to be aware of this.

Comment: what about the concern raised in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623078/initializing-zurb-foundations-tooltip-with-angularjs

Answer (score 4):

There is a native angularJs support for foundation. Check out [Angular Foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/).

> **Angular Foundation** is a port of the AngularUI team's excellent angular-bootstrap project for use in the Foundation framework.

It has no dependencies but angular library itself and foundation CSS only.

Comment: I just `bower` installed `angular-foundation` and seems to work correctly.

Comment: This library doesn't initialize the Javascript components by default (I'm on v0.3.1 - 2014-08-19)

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't. Instead it allows you to make use of almost all foundation javascript plugins.

Comment: Link to Angular foundation is no longer active

Answer (score 3):

One method that I've been using is to just include a `<script>` tag at the end of my partial / template.

This way, I can *target* just the new content of each partial -- instead of making foundation js re-parse the whole DOM.

for example, in my header.html:

```
<header id="app-header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <dd>
      <a href="#panel1">Panel 1</a>
      <div id="panel1" class="content">
        Loren Ipsum blah blah blah....
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</header>

<!-- add this tag on bottom of template / partial -->
<script>$('#app-header').foundation();</script>
```

Especially if your app has a lot of DOM elements on the page, this can improve perfomance considerably.

Comment: granted, you usually want to avoid polluting your DOM with `<script>` tags, but this actually winds up keeping your javascript code cleaner, and separates concerns / modularizes your components better than adding code via `.run()` or to your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
app.run(function($timeout){
    $timeout(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    }, 500);
});
```

It solved my issue trying to get Foundation reveal working.

Answer (score 0):

**For TypeScript Angular 4 (or 2) projects using Components:**

According to the given blog post,  declare $ as a variable in the component and then call `$(document).foundation();` in `ngOnInit()` worked for me!

> With Angular, components are injected into the DOM after Foundation
>   has loaded. When you load up a new component, and inject it,
>   Foundation doesn’t know it’s there. We need to tell Foundation to
>   reinitialize and bind again, so these attributes will get wired up. http://justindavis.co/2017/06/15/using-foundation-6-in-angular-4/

```
{ import Component } from '@angular/core';

declare let $: any;      // TO ACCESS JQUERY '$' FUNCTION

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html'
  // other stuff here
});

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).foundation();    // CALL foundation() INITIALIZATION FUNCTION FROM HERE
  }
}
```