# Foundation and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am modifying an application using Zurb's Foundation framework for responsiveness and AngularJS. There is a bug where data displayed in a table with `<tr ng-repeat="obj in entries">...</tr>` has `<td>`'s which are hidden/shown based on Foundation's responsive rules. Unfortunately, when the angular model is updated, Foundation doesn't re-flow the newly rendered DOM.

I have tried using
`$(document).foundation('table')` as I found in extensive google searching, but this didn't actually trigger a reflow of the responsive collapsed table. I also added a directive to trigger a simple `$(window).trigger('resize')` which works for the first call, but any subsequent calls do not.

Anybody else run into this?

Comment: There's a couple of answers here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753003/angularjs-initialize-zurb-foundation-js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing two technologies that dont play nice together.

The JS assets provided by Zurb Foundation will inevitably have conflicts with the digest cycle in AngularJS. For this reason --- Angular-Bootstrap projects emerged to transform jquery plugins into AngularJS directives.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I don't believe the same level of support, "if any", is offered for Zurb Foundation.

Comment: @StephanMuller Thanks, exactly what I was looking for while Foundation for Apps is being pulled together (http://zurb.com/article/1312/the-next-foundation)

Answer (score 9):

Angular UI Bootstrap was not completely framework agnostic so we had to do some modifications to adapt it to Foundation. You can see the result and code here: http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/.

Comment: @sorich87 Does anyone knows about Orbit? foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not forced to use Bootstrap with Angular all the times.

You can use this project here http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/ which tries to do the same as UI BOOTSTRAP.

Also you can reference this thread [Using Zurb Foundation Interchange with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019132/using-zurb-foundation-interchange-with-angularjs)

Hope this helps!