# Zurb Foundation 5 toggle-topbar not working

Tags: zurb-foundation

Just switched my rails project to test Zurb Foundation 5 and now the toggle-topbar menu is not working.

When the viewport is small, the top bar menu items disappear and the menu icon is displayed as before, but when I click on the menu icon nothing occurs.

I have the following code to display a top-bar menu.

```
<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"></li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
      <a>{href: "#"}
        <span>Menú</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
      <li>
        <a class="i fi-home">{href: "/ui/home"}
          &nbsp;Inicio</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>{href: "/ui/wine_reviews"} Críticas de Vinos</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>{href: "/ui/wine_tastings"} Catas y Maridajes</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>{href: "/ui/blogs"} Noticias</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li>
        <a>{href: "#"}
          <i class="fi-lock"></i>
          &nbsp;Club TastaVi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

It's a top-bar menu contained in my grid.

Comment: I have the same issue, and many others!

Comment: Easy fix is to change `<nav class="top-bar">` to `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>`.

Comment: @JGallardo - doesn't fix it for me :/

Comment: I actually have the idea that something in the CSS needs to be changed. I only noticed the issue after a friend opened my site on his iPhone. On my Galaxy Note I didn't experience the issue. After fumbling around on the iPhone, I noticed that if I "click" left of the menu icon, the menu actually shows up as it should...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the Foundation.topbar.js file. The following section of code

```
breakpoint : function () {
        return matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['medium']).matches;
    }
```

needs to be changed to

```
breakpoint : function () {
        return !matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['topbar']).matches;
    }
```

Comment: Did this work for you? because I fixed it easily by following the suggestion to change `<nav class="top-bar">` to `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>`.

Comment: @JGallardo - Yes. Adding the data-topbar attribute fixed it for medium sized screens. I needed my fix to get it working for small sized screens. When did you download Foundation 5? I heard that the code in Topbar.js was corrected sometime today and you might have received a new build with the patch in place.

Comment: The updated code is now `breakpoint : function () {
      return $(window).width() <= this.settings.breakPoint || $('html').hasClass('lt-ie9');
    },` but I think I am missing something to initialize this

Comment: @JGallardo I had to add your code to overwrite the breakpoint function in Foundation.libs.topbar for some reason. So, apparently it's still not fixed with the latest version.

Comment: none of the solutions provided here is working for me; I already have the `data-topbar` and @user1 code was already in my foundation.topbar.js file, though I'm loading the min version. any other thoughts?

Comment: @ithil - Could you get a fresh copy of Foundation 5 from the Zurb website and try again? Also, do you see any error in your javascript console?

Comment: @user1 you're right, I'm getting plenty of errors the first being `$(...).foundation is not a function` even if I do `$(document).foundation();` before the <body> close tag. so it's all my JS that's failing, I'll double check

Comment: Where in the rails application exactly would I change this code? I can't seem to find the exact foundation.topbar.js file...

Comment: @himanish.k - This thread is from 2013 and no longer relevant. Download a new copy of foundation from the zurb website and start a new question if it still doesnt work for you.

Comment: I did open up another question and found the answer. Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855110/zurb-foundation-5-rails-4-toggle-topbar-wont-work

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with the top bar. After comparing zurbs code with mine I noticed the difference.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
```

I was missing the data-topbar. After adding that mine topbar started working correctly.

Comment: This fixed it immediately

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI, there is another bug in the topbar that breaks scrolling.  You need to change line 38 of foudation.topbar.js from:

```
self.settings.stick_topbar = topbar;
```

to

```
self.settings.sticky_topbar = topbar;
```

This has been fixed in the 5.0.3 release but as of last night, the Foundation website was still serving 5.0.2

Comment: I can verify that as of 12th of Feb 2014, this change still hasn't been made in the served version of Foundation. Strange, that after three months, Zurb still hasn't updated..

Answer (score 2):

Here's the minimum you need to get it working... I was missing `$(document).foundation();`...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.7/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" data-options="is_hover: false" role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">Mobile Parent Links</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href=""><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section" style="left: 0%;">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="has-dropdown not-click"><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html">Item 1</a>

                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li>
                    <li class="parent-link show-for-small">
                        <a class="parent-link js-generated" href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html">Item 1</a></li>

<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.7/js/foundation/foundation.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.7/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For Angular.js, also do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753003/angularjs-initialize-zurb-foundation-js#answer-17367185

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem before. For me, it works when I include the topbar.js inside the body and under the foundation.js.

So, instead of

```
<head>
   <script src="../js/foundation.js"></script>
   <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
....
</head>
```

Try to put the topbar.js inside the body like this

```
<head>
   <script src="../js/foundation.js"></script>
....
</head>

<body>
   <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
....
</body>
```

Comment: just to know, where is your `$(document).foundation();` call?

Comment: I put it at the end of the body

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with Foundation 5.1.1.  None of the above suggested fixes were applicable for me (I already had the `data-topbar` attribute, and the `breakpoint` function was already updated in this release of Foundation).  I'm testing my code-in-development with Firefox on MacOS.  My Javascript includes are at the end of the body.

In my case, the problem was fixed by upgrading Zurb to version 5.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that issue since yesterday evening & going through all of such threads, nothing trick really helped. At last, following are the steps that helped me resolving the issue:

1. [Re-Downloaded updated Complete Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html).
2. Included html meta(viewport) tag that I was missing earlier.
3. I'm including the files at my page in this way:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation/foundation.css"/>`

    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation/app.css"/>`

     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`
   `<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>`
   `<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>`
4. Called Foundation function in jquery rather than js as below:
   `<script>`
   `$(document).ready(function() {`
   `$(document).foundation();`
   `});`
   `</script>`