# Zurb Foundation 5 + Rails 4 : toggle-topbar won't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have tried everything in my knowledge (however little there is), but I can not make the top bar menu render properly on small screens. I want the menu to reduce down to a clickable menu item on small screens, basically responsive behaviour from the menu. Apparently the following code alone should make it work, but it doesn't.

```
<header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 large-centered small-12 small-centered columns">
          <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="title-area">
                  <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="left">
                  <li><%= link_to('Link', {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'}) %></li>
                  <!-- other links -->    
                </ul>
                <ul class="right">
                    <li><%= link_to('Link', {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'}) %></li>
                    <!-- other links -->
                </ul>  
            </section>
          </nav>      
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I think it has something to do with javascript related to Foundation but I'm not sure what it is exactly.

**EDIT:**

application.js :

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require foundation
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

application.scss

```
/*
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 */

@import 'custom';
```

The custom.scss file imports foundation_and_overrides.scss .

Comment: have you added `//= require foundation` and `$(document).foundation();` is you application.js?

Comment: Added application.js and application.scss in the question.

Comment: Change order position of `//= require foundation` in below `//= require jquery_ujs`.

Comment: Tried that as well. And included script tags for jquery files in the head, tried that too.

Comment: I thought, You have to follow this https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout/issues/4

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've found a solution that works for me and posted it as the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestion below, make sure to change the href in

```
<ul class="title-area">
     <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

to href="" .

I've copied the last comment from http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2348-foundation-5-topbar-menu-not-responding-on-rails4

You will need to add

gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

to your Gem file then do the usual bundle install

Following this change your javascript manifest file (application.js) to run in the following order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
$(function(){ $(document).foundation({});
// any other code etc
//= require turbolinks
```

This will ensure turbolinks runs AFTER everything else (especially foundation in this case).